# how to prove the transfer function of the decomposed form is the following?

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory

We know that for an uncontrollable state space model of the following form:

$\begin{array}{l}
\dot x\left( t \right) = Ax\left( t \right) + Bu\left( t \right)\\
y\left( t \right) = Cx\left( t \right) + Du\left( t \right)
\end{array}$

it has a transfer function $G\left( s \right) = C{\left( {SI - A} \right)^{ - 1}}B + D$.

Furthermore, we can associate a controllable Kalman decomposition:

$\begin{array}{l}
\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\frac{{d\left( {{{\bar x}_c}} \right)}}{{dt}}}\\
{\frac{{d\left( {{{\bar x}_{\bar c}}} \right)}}{{dt}}}
\end{array}} \right] = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{{\bar A}_c}}&{{{\bar A}_{12}}}\\
0&{{{\bar A}_{\bar c}}}
\end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{{\bar x}_c}}\\
{{{\bar x}_{\bar c}}}
\end{array}} \right] + \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{{\bar B}_c}}\\
0
\end{array}} \right]u\\
y = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{{\bar C}_c}}&{{{\bar C}_{\bar c}}}
\end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{{\bar x}_c}}\\
{{{\bar x}_{\bar c}}}
\end{array}} \right] + Du
\end{array}$

my question is: how to prove that the new transfer function is: $G\left( s \right) = {{\bar C}_c}{\left( {SI - {{\bar A}_c}} \right)^{ - 1}}{{\bar B}_c} + D$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controllable Kalman decomposition is a [linear transformation](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Representations/SysRepTransformations/SS2SS.html), i.e. $\bar{x} = T\,x$ with $T$ non-singular. So the state space model in the controllable Kalman decomposition $(\bar{A}, \bar{B}, \bar{C}, \bar{D})$ is related to the initial state space model $(A,B,C,D)$ according to

\begin{align}
\bar{A} &= T\,A\,T^{-1}, \\
\bar{B} &= T\,B, \\
\bar{C} &= C\,T^{-1}, \\
\bar{D} &= D.
\end{align}

For any such non-singular $T$ is follows that

$$
G(s) = \bar{C}\,(s\,I - \bar{A})^{-1} \bar{B} + \bar{D} = C\,T^{-1}\,(s\,I - T\,A\,T^{-1})^{-1} T\,B + D, \tag{1}
$$

which simplifies to the following when using the [push-through identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity#Discussion)

$$
G(s) = C\,(s\,I - A)^{-1} B + D. \tag{2}
$$

So any non-singular $T$ does not change the transfer function $G(s)$ associated with the state space model.

---

If there exists such a $T$ such that

$$
\bar{A} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\bar{A}_c & \bar{A}_{12} \\
0 & \bar{A}_\bar{c}
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
\bar{B} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\bar{B}_c \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
\bar{C} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\bar{C}_c & \bar{C}_\bar{c}
\end{bmatrix},
$$

it follows that the transfer function $G(s)$ can be obtained using $(1)$. It can be noted that due to upper block triangular structure of $\bar{A}$ it holds that

\begin{align}
(s\,I - \bar{A})^{-1} &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
s\,I-\bar{A}_c & -\bar{A}_{12} \\
0 & s\,I-\bar{A}_\bar{c}
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}, \tag{3a} \\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
(s\,I-\bar{A}_c)^{-1} & (s\,I-\bar{A}_c)^{-1} \bar{A}_{12} (s\,I-\bar{A}_\bar{c})^{-1} \\
0 & (s\,I-\bar{A}_\bar{c})^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}. \tag{3b}
\end{align}

From this it follows that multiplying $(3)$ by $\bar{B}$ yields

$$
(s\,I - \bar{A})^{-1} \bar{B} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
(s\,I-\bar{A}_c)^{-1} \bar{B}_c \\ 0
\end{bmatrix},
$$

after which I assume it is clear that

$$
G(s) = \bar{C}_c(s\,I-\bar{A}_c)^{-1} \bar{B}_c + D.
$$